# Can I add into my nuget nupkg my library that has a version of .net core and .net46?

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-core

Can I add into my nuget nupkg my library that has a version of .net core and .net40, .net45? I know how to package .net40, .net45, but what I can see there is a command for .net core to package them `dotnet pack`. Can somebody bring some clarity on this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's very easy. You can prepare .nuspec file and lib folder under the same folder. Inside of the lib folder there should be the same structure as before (using nuget.exe utility):

lib

- net40
- net45
- net46
- portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10
- dotnet

So `dotnet` folder is all about .net core just put .net core binaries there and execute:

```
nuget pack "path to your .nuspec file"
```

and then:

```
nuget setApiKey "YourNugetApiKey" -Source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package

nuget push "path to your generated .nupkg file" -Source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package
```